# ADO - in case of error: How to get information about Query Line number?

Tags: sql, ado

In SQL Server Management Studio using this following SQL query:

```sql
SELECT
    [testing_error]
FROM
    [baza].dbo.[sprawy]
```

I get this error:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
> Invalid column name 'testing_error'

I know why this error occurs, and I do not need help in fixing them.

But....

As so far I already checked [Errors Collection (ADO)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/errors-collection-ado?view=sql-server-ver15) and used this collection but only `Invalid column name 'testing_error'.` error is taken from errors object.

My question is about: how using ADO get the information about the "Line"?

Because I'm looking for a way to get the information which line of the SQL query the error is located on.